# .NET/C# REST Api Messages to Queue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, nancy

I am new to .NET/C# and I am wondering how oyu could achieve the following scenario:

I need a REST Api with has one endpoint, which accepts a message(string).
That message should be stored in a Queue and then there should be one or multiple Threads that consume and process this Queue.

I do not want to use Hangfire, RabbitMq etc. The only thing that I have seen is to use NancyFx to create the Rest API in a Console application and from there I can achieve the described scenario, but is it possible in .NET Core WebApi, because you cannot create Threads there ?

Comment: You want to send the message from web API to queue and consume the messages from the queue in the same web API application?

Comment: Note the BlockingCollection is your friend here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview

Comment: @chetan I want to receive messages via a Rest Api and yes the question is: if i want to put it to a queue an process it, should I do it in the same application ? If possible, how ?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you, but how could I implement this in a .NET Core WebApi and how do I create a Thread in a WebApi to process that queue ?

Comment: See docs here "Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft but is this reliable ? Or is Hangfire the way to go ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Asp.Net Core Webapi and use `Task` Instead of `Thread`. If you don't use any other third parties such as RabbitMq, Redis, or other message queue, you have to create a shared variable such as a `Dictionary` or a `List` and implement synchronization mechanism (such as using `Lock`) by yourself to avoid any problem caused by concurrency.